# Function for split digits in list and unique number/code for every digit

Tags: python, list, input, split, unique

I have a data input which I want to bring into a specific shape.

Data looks like this:

```
01211231202143244400222255340042523252102440536423024350201113345340514003134
20023230143300003201455331343005145134541545264403161213336031512541125234215
01203204313112402314341530533423155434004002652564464622316236363153203455225
```

My code:

```
with open('Dataday8.in') as file: 
    data = [i for i in file.read().split()]
```

After the code it looks like:

```
data = ['01211231202143244400222255340042523252102440536423024350201113345340514003', '2002323014330000320145533134300514513454154526440316121333603151254112523421', '0120320431311240231434153053342315543400400265256446462231623636315320345522']
```

Buy I want it to be seperates after every digit (but each line should be in one bracket). Does not matter what I try my code never brings me to the goal.

After this I would like to give every digit in the list a unique number that I can work with it in a loop.

Thanks for any help

This is the code I tried to split after every digit in the list:

```
[x for x in data.split('\n')]
```

Comment: So you technically want a 2-D list? Something like : [[12354],[478965]]

Comment: `data = [list(i) for i in file.read().split()]` ?

Comment: yes, is that what you wanted?

Comment: Yees @MauriceMeyer that solved the probem!

Comment: Is there an option where I can convert the numbers to integers in the same line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am simply reporting [Maurice Meyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7216865/maurice-meyer)'s answer which perfectly solves the problem for better future readability. Furthermore, if you want to get integers, you simply need to di

```
data = [list(int(i)) for i in file.read().split()]
data = [[int(elem) for elem in row] for row in data]
```

Comment: Thank you! If i add the Int() unfortunately i get this error: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: I've changed my answer.

Comment: Assuming the error you get is `int object is not iterable`, what you probably want is actually `data = [[int(i)] for i in file.read().split()]`.

Answer (score 0):

Although already solved by [Sala](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75007288/19116377), i think your problem of `int object is not iterable` could be solved with this:

```
data = list([int(elem) for elem in row] for row in (i for i in file.read().split()))
```

You can also write it like this:

```
data = list(list(int(elem) for elem in row) for row in (i for i in file.read().split()))
```

This is a one-liner but of course you can break it down.